# Transferring data over JSON securely

Tags: json, web-services, security, authentication

I've setup a web server and can exchange data between it and my iPhone by using JSON.

Is JSON already encrypted? I'm trying to make an app that people can use. I'm not sure how to securely verify a user. Right now I'm having them send some information that uniquely identifies them along with their GET requests.

But couldn't someone easily pick this up, and then replay the GET request to the server to access the same information?

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

JSON is not automagically encrypted, no.

Secure your server with SSH. This ***should*** prevent most MITM type attacks. If you are extremely worried about replay attacks from the client side (browser), you will probably need oAuth + a secure nonce.

No security measure will protect you 100%, you have to compromise security vs performance.

Comment: If I use the https address of my server when transferring JSON, then is the data automagically encrypted?

Comment: Yes, assuming you actually have SSL configured for the server.

Comment: How can I check if the server is using SSL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about MITM attacks, most likely someone sniffing requests on your network and then replaying them, you could set up SSL and send the JSON request via that, which would prevent the attack.
The only other thing is that via GET your security variables will be exposed in the URL.
Whether it is ideal form is what kind of information you are transferring and what other authentication you are using.

http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/quick-steps-on-setting-up-apache-ssl-php-json-on-freebsd-8-0/